# How to store unordered_set to a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-set

I want to use a vector to store several unordered_set.

Here is my test codes:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<unordered_set<int>> v1;
    unordered_set<int> s1 = {1,2}, s2 = {3,2};
    v1[0] = s1;
    v1[1] = s2;
    for (auto &s : v1[0]) {
        cout << s << " ";
    }
}
```

And I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` .

My question is: How should I modify my codes?

Comment: You have `0` `unordered_set`s stored in the `vector`. You must add at least one before you can do `v1[0]` (which accesses the first `unordered_set`).

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo  Sorry, I didn't noticed that, I have already edit it

Comment: It's still the same problem. `v1` is empty. You can either do `v1.push_back(s1); v1.push_back(s2);` or create the vector with `2` sets in it from the start.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your vector does not have elements 0 and 1. Either initialize the vector with required number of elements, or insert the elements into an empty vector as below:

```
int main(){
        vector<unordered_set<int>> v1;
        unordered_set<int> s1 = {1,2}, s2 = {3,2};
        v1.push_back(s1);
        v1.push_back(s2);
        for (auto &s : v1[0]) {
            cout << s << " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, it is better to include some essential parts of the answer verbally here along with the code.

Comment: OK - updated it

Comment: @GRZa Thank you so much, I'm too used to python

Comment: NP at all, HNY:)